# ContextMenu is empty on first left-click of wpf button

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I have a button in my view with a dynamic context menu that I want to activate via right or left clicks. When I left-click first, the menu is empty. When I right-click, or left-click after a right-click, the menu shows with the contents of favouriteItemList.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932889/wpf-mvvm-contextmenu-binding-isopen-to-model), which looks like it might be an answer, but I don't understand enough about WPF to get it to work with my code.

The other thing is that `SelectFavouriteCommand` doesn't seem to be called when I click an item in the menu.

View model class:

```
{
  public ViewModel(IFolderService folderService)
  {
    this.SelectFavouriteCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(this.SelectFavourite);
    this.favouriteItemList = new MvxObservableCollection<SelectedFolder>(folderService.GetFolders());
  }

  public IMvxAsyncCommand SelectFavouriteCommand { get; }

  private MvxObservableCollection<SelectedFolder> favouriteItemList;
  public MvxObservableCollection<SelectedFolder> FavouriteItemList
  {
    get => this.favouriteItemList;
    set
    {
      this.favouriteItemList = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FavouriteItemList);
    }
  }

  private async Task SelectFavourite()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

In the view xml:

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="BtnUseFavourite" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,0,5,0">
  <StackPanel>
    <Image Source="/Images/ImageFavoriteIcon.png" />
  </StackPanel>
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                  <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
  <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding FavouriteItemList}">
      <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
          <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Path}"></Setter>
          <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectFavouriteCommand}" ></Setter>
        </Style>
      </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
  </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For calling command try below code
`<Setter Property="Command" 
Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectFavouriteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to invoke the `SelectFavouriteCommand` when clicking on the `MenuItem`, you should bind to the `Button`'s `DataContext` using the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding FavouriteItemList}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Path}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.SelectFavouriteCommand, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

And a context menu is only expected to be opened when *right*-clicking on a `Button`. Left-clicking would invoke a command or a click event handler.